# Import Parse class to algolia

Tags: parse-platform, algolia

I am trying to import my class (2500 records) from Parse.com into an Algolia index. There is a limit of 100 records by default which obviously is not working for me. Even if I use `query.limit = 1000;`

How can the below code be used to import my whole class?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createIndex", function(request, response) {

var algoliasearch = require('cloud/algoliasearch.parse.js');
var client = algoliasearch('9PsdfsdWVU7', '3b24e897bfb4esdfsdfsdf209e25c28');
var index = client.initIndex('exercises');

console.log("running");

var objectsToIndex = [];

//Create a new query for Contacts
var query = new Parse.Query('Exercises');

query.limit = 1000;
// Find all items
query.find({
    success: function(exercises) {
        // prepare objects to index from contacts
        objectsToIndex = exercises.map(function(exercise) {
            // convert to regular key/value JavaScript object
            exercise = exercise.toJSON();

            // Specify Algolia's objectID with the Parse.Object unique ID
            exercise.objectID = exercise.objectId;

            return exercise;
        });

        // Add or update new objects
        index.saveObjects(objectsToIndex, function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            console.log('Parse<>Algolia import done');
        });
        response.success("worked");
    },
    error: function(err) {
        response.error("failed");
        throw err;
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Instead of `find`, did you try `each` ?

Comment: I get `TypeError: object is not a function` on the line above the`query.each` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com has a find limit, and all other limitations when you want to "get all the objects", you can find more information here: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#performance-limits-and-other-considerations

For your current issue you could do this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createIndex", function(request, response) {
    var algoliasearch = require('cloud/algoliasearch.parse.js');
    var client = algoliasearch('9PsdfsdWVU7', '3b24e897bfb4esdfsdfsdf209e25c28');
    var index = client.initIndex('exercises');

    console.log("running");

    //Create a new query for Contacts
    var Exercises = Parse.Object.extend('Exercises');
    var query = new Parse.Query(Exercises);
    var skip = -1000;
    var limit = 1000;

    saveItems();

    function saveItems() {
        skip += limit;
        query.skip(skip + limit);
        query.limit(limit);
        query.find({success: sucess, error: error});
    }

    function sucess(exercices) {
        if (exercices.length === 0) {
            response.success("finished");
            return;
        }


        exercises = exercises.map(function(exercise) {
            // convert to regular key/value JavaScript object
            exercise = exercise.toJSON();

            // Specify Algolia's objectID with the Parse.Object unique ID
            exercise.objectID = exercise.objectId;

            return exercise;
        });

        index.saveObjects(exercises, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            console.log('Parse<>Algolia import done');
            response.success("worked");
            saveItems();
        });

    }

    function error() {
        response.error("failed");
        throw err;
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not get around the limit of 100 results. My code works as your example would. By default there are only 100 results returned. You can extend this to 1000 however this still isn't good enough if you have 3000 records.

Comment: Ok so the limit was on parse side, I updated the answer